# How do I access 2nd level of multiple-dimension array in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an array within my ProductClass object (the subcategory array):

```
   class ProductCategory{
    public $name;
    public $id;
    public $subcategory = array();

    public function __construct($categoryName, $categoryId, $subcategoryname, $subcategoryid){
        $this->name = $categoryName;
        $this->id = $categoryId;

        $this->subcategory = array (
            "subcategoryname" => $subcategoryname,
            "subcategoryid" => $subcategoryid
        );

    }
}
```

I have the object that looks like this:

```
[0] => ProductCategory Object
    (
        [name] => Flower
        [id] => 1
        [subcategory] => Array
            (
                [subcategoryname] => Buds
                [subcategoryid] => 8
            )

    )

[1] => ProductCategory Object
    (
        [name] => Concentrate
        [id] => 2
        [subcategory] => Array
            (
                [subcategoryname] => Live Resin
                [subcategoryid] => 15
            )

    )

[2] => ProductCategory Object
    (
        [name] => Concentrate
        [id] => 2
        [subcategory] => Array
            (
                [subcategoryname] => Shatter
                [subcategoryid] => 5
            )

    )
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to access the subcategory name and subcategory id.

I can access the name and id easily like so: `$category->name` and `$category->id`.

I used `print_r` like so: `print_r($category->subcategory)` and I get an output that looks like this:

`Array ( [subcategoryname] => Buds [subcategoryid] => 8 )`

So I know it's there. I get `Array` when I use `echo $category->subcategory`.

However, when it comes to getting the subcategory name and subcategory id values, nothing I'm trying appears to be working.

I've tried:

`$category->subcategory->subcategoryname`

Also:

`$category->subcategory[0]`

Also:

`$category->subcategory['subcategoryname']`

Also:

`$category->subcategory['subcategory']['subcategoryname']`

Nothing I do seems to be returning the name (or id).

Comment: `$category->subcategory['subcategoryname']` should work.

Comment: Well, that seemed to do it .. but I thought I already tried that. Maybe I had a spelling error or something. Am I seeing things or is that not identical to the third thing I listed?

Comment: It does appear identical to the third option. Maybe you did indeed typo?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Maybe you could post your comment as an answer so that it can get accepted since it worked out for Soulfire?

Comment: Agreed - I guess it was one of those "oh wow I'm an idiot" moments and I had a typo in it, but if you post your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it.